# Создание n массивов

Tags: массивы, c

Требуется преобразовать входной текстовый файл в выходной двоичный c массивов типа char фиксированной размерности str

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
FILE *input = fopen("D:/input.txt", "r");
char buf[256]="";
char ukaz[1000];
char *x;
int size_of_str=0, str=0, i=0, c=0;
size_t n_obj, count;
if(input != NULL)
{
    while(fgets(buf,256,input) != NULL)
    {
        size_of_str=strlen(buf);
        if (size_of_str > str)
            str=size_of_str;
        c++;        
    }
    while(fgets(buf,256,input) != NULL)
    {
        x = (char *) malloc(str * sizeof(char));            
        ukaz[i]=x; //насколько я понимаю это набор указателей на массивы
        i++;
    }

    printf("Razmer:%d, Kolvo strok:%d\n",str,c);
    getchar();
}
fclose(input);
```

}

А вот как вывести все массивы в преобразованный файл что-то мозгов не хватает.

Comment: Компилятор выдает ошибку  invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
while(fgets(buf,256,input) != NULL)
{
size_of_str=strlen(buf);
if (size_of_str > str)
str=size_of_str;
c++;        
}
while(fgets(buf,256,input) != NULL)
{
            x = (char *) malloc(str * sizeof(char));            
            strcpy(x,buf);
            ukaz[i]=x; 
            i++;
        }
        FILE *input = fopen("D:/input.bin", "wb");
        void rewind(FILE *input);
        for(i=0; i<c; i++)
        {
            fwrite(ukaz, sizeof (char), str, input);
      }

Comment: студентота попёрла... зачёты жать начали. бгггг

Comment: лол нет, пока лабы. Могу в принципе сделать и без динамических массивов, но хотелось бы разобраться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут всё не очень хорошо. По порядку.
После прохождения файла в первом цикле, тебе надо его переоткрыть - переместить указатель на позицию начала файла. Функция rewind тебе в помощь.
Во втором цикле ты только готовишь структуру данных - выделяешь память под вектор строк, но не записываешь туда считанную из файла в buf строку. Нужно скопировать buf в x, а потом уже присваивать i-му элементу вектора этот самый х. strcpy - тебе в помощь.
Чтобы записать инфу в бинарный файл нужно его сначала создать/открыть с режимом wb. Буква "b" для винды важна. 
Запись в в файл будешь производить с помощью функции fwrite, по порядку для каждого элемента массива ukaz.
з.ы. и пожалуй стоит после выделения памяти проверять указатель на NULL.